# Transle multiple SELECT rules into a single DQL query

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I working on a project using `Symfony 2.7` and `Doctrine`. The project manages different Entities:
One `User` can have any number of `Orders` that include one or more `OrderItems`.

Now I would like to include a messaging component, that allows to automatically send e-mails to the users. Each message has its own set of `Rules` that specifies the `Users` that should receive the message.

Example:

- All `Users`
- `Users` with user number between X and Y
- `Users` with lastname "Doe"
- `Users` that have at least one `Order`
- `Users` that have an `Order` with `OrderItem` XY
- `Users` that have an `Order` that is not yet payed
- etc.

**Question is:** Is it possible to translate **all** rules of a message into **one single** DQL SELECT query?

Combining the rules that only effect the `User` into one query is no problem:

```
public function getMatchingUsers($rules) {
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb_expense->select('u')
        ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u');      

    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        $property = $rule->getProperty();
        $operator = $rule->getOperator(); // --> =, !=, <, >, <= or >=
        $value = $rule->getValue();

        switch ($property) {
            case ($property == UserMessage::FUNC_USER_NO): {
                $qb
                    ->andWhere('u.userNo :operator :value')
                    ->setParameter('operator', $operator)
                    ->setParameter('value', $value);                
                break;
            }
            case ($property == UserMessage::FUNC_NAME): {
                $qb
                    ->andWhere('u.name = :value')
                    ->setParameter('value', $value);                
                break;
            }
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**But how to add/include the rules that do effect the `User` but his `Orders` or even the `OrderItems`**?

Problem is, that different rules would require different queries (simple SELECT, SELECT with JOIN, COUNT of Orders, etc.)

Is this solvable in just one query?

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine Query builder has a method called `addSelect()` you can then add different select statements..

```
$qb
  ->select('u')
  ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u');

if(condition)
{
  $qb->addSelect('o')
     ->join('u.orders', 'o');
}
```

[Doctrine Docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)